# Ruby on Rails Relationships for Two Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-migrations

I have two different models.

**Item Model**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    attr_accessible :make, :model, :name, :purchasedfrom, :qrcode, :serialnumber, :category_id
end
```

**Event Model**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    attr_accessible :name, :location_id, :category_id
end
```

I cannot figure out how to do the following:

- An `Event` has multiple `Item` that can be at the `Event`.
- An `Event` history still shows `Items` from a particular event.
- Would show items from event: **localhost/event/:id/items**

I cannot figure out this for the life of me.  If I can get some direction in this issue, I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks in advance for all of your help.

I have seen the use of `:through` which I believe I would have to use here.

Comment: You should either use `has many :through` or `has_and_belongs_to_many` relation.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, here you can write something like this in Event model.

```
class Event
  def items
    category.items
  end
end
```

then in controller,

```
@event = Event.find(params[:id])
@items = @event.try(:items)
```

Comment: Make sure to double to check to see if the `category` association exists before calling the `items` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

If one `Category` can have many `Events` I think you must add `event_id` in `Item` to be able to know exactly what `Items` that has been on exactly one `Event`.
(And in that case add relations for that).

Or join table between `Event` and `Item` and has_and_belongs_to_many if one `Item` can be on many `Events`

EDIT:

If it's like that, add table `events_items`, relation `has_and_belongs_to_many :items` (in `Event` and `:events` in `Item`), and read **documentation** for `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Otherwise, if you are looking for `Items` that has been on a certain `Event` you will find all `Items` that have been on **all** `Events` that has the same `Category` as the `Event` you are investigating.

Comment: I am really confused.  An `Item` can be at an `Event`.  An `Item` is like a speaker or microphone used at said `Event`.  So we have multiple `Item` at an `Event`.   The `Event` is over and the items return back to where they are stored.  However, if I view the event, I can see the items that were apart of that `Event`.  The `Event` table has `:name, :location_id, :event_date, :category_id`.  So HOW do I associate MULTIPLE `Item` at different `Events`?

Comment: I changed in my suggestion, hope that answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you would want to do is:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :event
end
```

and for Events:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :items
end
```

Then you should be able to view the items for an event by calling:

```
@event = Event.find_by_id(:id)
@event.items.all
```

Comment: I am really confused.  An `Item` can be at an `Event`.  An `Item` is like a speaker or microphone used at said `Event`.  So we have multiple `Item` at an `Event`.   The `Event` is over and the items return back to where they are stored.  However, if I view the event, I can see the items that were apart of that `Event`.  The `Event` table has `:name, :location_id, :event_date, :category_id`.  So HOW do I associate MULTIPLE `Item` at different `Events`?